# updating mysql table row by checking date using strtotime

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update *row/rows* if the current date is equals or greater to the date in the database.
Example:

```
$sql = "UPDATE ca_dreams SET d_matured_status=1 WHERE d_pay_date='"
       . time() . "'";
```

How can I get `d_pay_date` to be converted to time using `strtotime` then compared to `time()`.

Please note I want this to update as many rows as possible.

Comment: what data type does 'd_pay_date' have ?

Comment: just varchar saved in the format d/m/YYYY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time()` is a PHP function, and you don't need to involve PHP when MySQL has functions which are just as usable.

What you'll need is `DATE()` to convert the `d_pay_date` column to a date (if it's already a specific date and not a timestamp, you don't need this function), then check against `CURDATE()`. Then compare against dates with `<=` (less or equal to).

```
$sql = "UPDATE ca_dreams SET d_matured_status=1 WHERE DATE(d_pay_date) <= CURDATE()":
```